# How to access an instance in eucalyptus?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, salesforce, cloud, eucalyptus

i have installed Eucalyptus Faststart (cloud-in-a-box) on vmware. i then launched the instance with pre-configured image of centos. but then i am not able to start the instance. the connect option for the instances is activated but then after the procedure of connecting the instance, it did not respond. also the start and stop options are continously inactive. finally how to access the instance?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simple connect to the instance by clicking on connect button. Go inside vmware where you installed eucalyptus on guest OS. Open terminal and to connect :

```
 ssh -i <keypair.pem> root@<public_ip_address>
```

Note: Keypair will be downloaded to the guest machine where you installed eucalyptus. Hope this helps !!